# group and sum double pair of number even if the order of the pairs are different but the same pairs of numbers

Tags: javascript

I need help to group and sum a double pair of numbers even if the order is different, the important thing is those double pair of numbers are the same, i have this code with js and unserscorejs but i dont know how to check if theres a pair with the same numbers in different order:

Logic example:

```
02 00(1.67$) -- > +1.67$
02 03(1.67$)
02 00(1.67$) -- > + 1.67$
00 03(1.67$) -- > +1.67$
00 00(1.67$)
03 00(1.67$) -- > +1.67$
```

Desired Result:

```
02 00(3.33$) --> 02 00 + 02 00
02 03(1.67$)
00 03(3.33$) --> 00 03 + 03 00
00 00(1.67$)
```

My code:

```js
let pairs = [{pair: '02 00',money: 1.67},{pair: '02 03',money: 1.67},{pair: '02 00',money: 1.67},{pair: '00 03',money: 1.67},{pair: '00 00',money: 1.67},{pair: '03 00',money: 1.67}]


    var groups = _.groupBy(pairs, 'pair');
    const result = _.map(groups, (value: any, key: any)  =>{
      return { 
        pair: key, 
        money: _.reduce(value, (total: any, o: { money: any; }) =>{ 
            return total + o.money;
        }, 0) 
      };
    });

//output
//[{pair: '02 00',money: 3.33},{pair: '02 03',money: 1.67},{pair: '00 03',money: 1.67},{pair: '00 00',money: 1.67},{pair: '03 00',money: 1.67}]

//expected output
//[{pair: '02 00',money: 3.33},{pair: '02 03',money: 1.67},{pair: '00 03',money: 3.33},{pair: '00 00',money: 1.67}]
```

Comment: Hey there.  You're showing something you're trying to do, but what's your question?  Are you asking someone to check if your code is good?  What do you need here?

Comment: thanks i have edited the question,  i dont know how to check if theres a pair with the same numbers in different order for example 00 03 with $1.67 and 03 00 $1.67 are same numbers but in different order, i need to group and sum this..

Comment: aha, got you.  I'll post an answer.  I won't be using underscorejs though, if that's okay, since I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: thanks very much, every help is super welcome :D

Comment: One simple way: `pair.split(' ').sort().join(' ')` will yield `'00 02'` for a pair value of either `'00 02'` or `'02 00'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to deal with this, you just need to do some string manipulation to compare the pairs.  I'll just post the code then go through it step by step.

```js
let pairs = [
    { pair: '02 00', money: 1.67 }, 
    { pair: '02 03', money: 1.67 },
    { pair: '02 00', money: 1.67 }, 
    { pair: '00 03', money: 1.67 },
    { pair: '00 00', money: 1.67 }, 
    { pair: '03 00', money: 1.67 }
]

const groupAndSum = (array) => {
    return Object.entries(
        array.reduce((acc, el) => {
            if (el.pair in acc) {
                acc[el.pair] += el.money
            } else {
                const key = el.pair.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')
                if (key in acc) acc[key] += el.money
                else acc[el.pair] = el.money
            }

            return acc
        }, {})
    )
    .map(([pair, money]) => ({ pair, money }))
}

console.log(groupAndSum(pairs))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Let's go from inside out.

1. First, we're reducing the array into an object with keys being the pairs and the values being sums of those pairs.  Meaning, after we go through the array with the reduce function, we get an object like this:

```
{ '02 00': 3.34, '02 03': 1.67, '00 03': 3.34, '00 00': 1.67 }
```

We get this by going through the objects in the pairs array 1 by 1.  We check if a certain pair exists in the accumulator object.

- If it does, we just increment the existing value in the accumulator object for that key by the money of the current object we've reached in our iteration.
- If it doesn't, we split the pair, reverse it, and rejoin it with a space to see if that string is a key that already exists in the accumulator object.

  - If it does exist, we increment the value of the existing key by the money of the object we've reached in our iteration.
  - If it doesn't exist, we create a new key in our accumulator object with the pair of the current object as the key and the money as the initial value.

2. Once we do that, we can take the entries of that object and turn them into an array with Object.entries.  That should give you an array like this:

```
[
  [ '02 00', 3.34 ],
  [ '02 03', 1.67 ],
  [ '00 03', 3.34 ],
  [ '00 00', 1.67 ]
]
```

3. Once we have the array, we can iterate over it to turn it back into the object we want, using map.
   This should convert the array above into the following result:

```
[
  { pair: '02 00', money: 3.34 },
  { pair: '02 03', money: 1.67 },
  { pair: '00 03', money: 3.34 },
  { pair: '00 00', money: 1.67 }
]
```